# Rails Scaffold references with select input and Entity label with generators

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-4, generator, crud, scaffolding

I'm trying to scaffold an app with Rails 4 and I had this little issue with the foreing keys, forms and Entity names. Here are some details:

```
rails g scaffold user_type name:string
rails g scaffold user name:string pass:string user_type:references
```

As you can see there is a simple relationship 1:n between an `user_type` and a `user`. An it generates the right scaffold on this case. Here is an image of the form generated,

[image]

But what I want as a result of the generator is the next form,

[image]

So the first change that I want from `rails g scaffold` is to generate, at least e 1:n relationships with a select input. And also I'm looking for a solution that involves the Models with a `label` or something. I need a `scaffold command` that finally generates this.

[image]

Witch means that the Entity `user_type` has his `name` attribute has a "presentation label".

I understand that I can create a generator from scratch, but I believe that I'm missing some options at the command line, because the change actually really tiny.

And can come up with a solution that involves inserting the right code in each CRUD but i'm planning to use this into a 150 tables database. Any help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can replace the templates that the scaffold generator uses by creating alternative templates in a `lib/templates/erb/scaffold` folder in your application root.

In this case, you will want to copy the original `_form.html.erb` template and replace the text field with a collection_select:

```
  <%- if attribute.reference? -%>
    <%%= f.label :<%= attribute.column_name %> %><br>
-   <%%= f.<%= attribute.field_type %> :<%= attribute.column_name %> %>
+   <%%= f.collection_select :<%= attribute.column_name %>, <%= attribute.name.camelize %>.all, :id, :name, prompt: true  %>
  <%- else -%>
```

More details can be read in [my post on the subject](http://daniel.fone.net.nz/blog/2014/02/01/customising-scaffold-views-in-ruby-on-rails/).

Comment: Why rails doesn't have this feature by default?

Comment: In order to use a select, the scaffold generator would have to identify that a column is a foreign key to another table and then decide what column in that other table should be used for the option names.  It would probably require some interaction with the user.  Having an interactive generator is obviously possible, but, from what I can tell, it's not how they usually work.